# Retrieving photos from S3 bucket at random

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have Icon images stored on my S3 Bucket, so when my web application runs and show an AWS Service name (at random), I want to show an appropriate icon for that service as well. I am using React, all Icon images are stored in an S3 bucket.

Comment: Can you add more details here?
Like what you want to actually achieve.
Is it:  You want to choose an icon file from s3 based on service name?

Comment: Yes, I want to choose an Icon of a service that will be displayed at that time

Comment: You mention two things: Choosing an item at random, and displaying an icon. Which specific part is causing the problem -- the choosing, or the displaying? The choosing will need to be totally within your own code -- you'll need a list of possible choices, and then use a random function to choose one. The list can either be hard-coded or it could list the contents of the S3 bucket to obtain the existing icons, then choose a random element from that list. If your problem is with _displaying_ the icon, then you'll need to provide us more information.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I can display services and descriptions at random, and in a separate S3 bucket i've stored service icons to display with each service. So I want to find out how I can link "services" bucket and "Icons" bucket so that whenever a service is displayed an appropriate icon is displayed with that service.   Hope this offered some clarity

Comment: The simplest method is to name the files the same as the service, and then print the name of the service and, next to it, use `<img src="s3://bucket/NAME-OF-SERVICE.jpg">`.